# Kindle Stuck on Lock Screen

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire

Somebody gave me a Kindle - it is an older model (only has one external button - the power button), but it is stuck on the lock screen and there is no way to get past it.

Things I've tried:

- [Holding the power button](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201734090) for 20 seconds to reset it
- Holding the power button for 40 seconds to reset it
- Using two fingers to try to swipe the screen (in case voice mode is activated)
- double-tapping the lock button
- charging it and then trying the 20-second reset

If I hold the power button for just a few seconds, the screen darkens and if asks me if I want to Shut Down or Cancel.  But tapping the buttons don't do anything - as if the screen won't detect taps anymore - I'm thinking it is a hardware issue.  However, on the lock screen, if I tap the lock button, it's background does shift transparency, so it's detecting something.

Any other ideas for this?  The tablet is too old to bother with Amazon Support, and I don't know anything more about it except that I can't get past the lock screen.  It powers on and off just fine, though.

[update]

Well, it's been quite a few days since my posting, and noone has any suggestions.  I don't know what to do except to try taking it apart and check to see if some cable is loose.